# Is it posible to hydrate dates as DateTime in mixed queries in doctrine2?

Tags: datetime, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a mixed query like this:

```
SELECT e, j.date_field FROM AcmeBundle:SomeEntity e JOIN e.joined_entity j
```

The query returns an array with the object and a string with the date, but I need dates hydrated as DateTime instances.

Is it posible to specify this in the query without building a custom hydrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not posible to do so without building a custom hydrator.

This has been fixed in a recent Doctrine version as stated in this [bug report](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-657).